# A generic function to copy char* in C

Tags: c, generics, stack, void-pointers

I'm trying to implement a generic stack (a singly linked list), I've worked out everything except when I have to handle character arrays.

The node:

```
typedef struct cvor {
    void *info;
    struct cvor *next;
} Cvor;
```

the stack typedef:

```
typedef struct {
    Cvor *tos;
    size_t velicinaInfo; // 
    freeFunction freeFn;
    copyFunction copyFn;
} Stek;
```

function to initialize a new stack:

```
void noviStek(Stek *stek, size_t velInfo, freeFunction freeFn, copyFunction copyFn)
{
    if (velInfo <= 0)
    {
        // element size can't be <=0
        printf("Velicina elementa ne moze biti 0.\n");
        return;
    }
    stek->tos = NULL;
    stek->velicinaInfo = velInfo;
    stek->freeFn = freeFn;
    stek->copyFn = copyFn;
}
```

the `freeFunction` and `copyFunction` are defined like this:

```
typedef void (*freeFunction)(void *);
typedef void (*copyFunction)(void **, void *);
```

For the primitive types(`int`, `double`,...) I don't need a specific copy function, but I need it for char*. This is what I have so far:

```
void copyString(void **dest, void *src)
{
    char *psrc = (char*) src;

    size_t size = strlen(psrc) + 1;

    *dest = calloc(size, 1);

    memcpy(*dest, src, size);
}
```

main looks like this:

```
char a[] = "helloooooooooo";
char b[] = "helloworld";
char c[] = "stringst";

Stek s;

noviStek(&s, sizeof(char*), NULL, copyString);

push(&s, a);
printf("tops: ");
stekTop(&s, pisi_string);
printf("\n");

push(&s, b);
printf("tops: ");
stekTop(&s, pisi_string);
printf("\n");

push(&s, c);
printf("tops: ");
stekTop(&s, pisi_string);
printf("\n");


//char d[100] = "";
char d[]="";
while (pop(&s, d))
{
    printf("d = %s ", d);
}

isprazniStek(&s);
```

`stekTop()` prints top of stack, `isprazniStek()` frees the stack.

The output is:

```
tops: helloooooooooo 
tops: helloworld 
tops: stringstring 
d = 
d = 
d =
```

So, if the `copyFn` is defined, it's used when `push()` and `pop()` are called to copy the info content of the node (for primitive types `copyFn` is `NULL`).

The problem is with the `pop` function, here's the function:

```
int pop(Stek *stek, void *element)
{
    if (isEmptyStek(stek))
        return 0;

    Cvor *p = stek->tos;

    if (stek->copyFn)
    {
        stek->copyFn(&element, p->info);
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(element, p->info, stek->velicinaInfo); // element = p->info;
    }

    stek->tos = p->next;

    if (stek->freeFn)
    {
        stek->freeFn(p->info);
    }

    free(p->info);
    free(p);

    return 1;
}
```

It doesn't copy `p->info` to `element` (it does when I use `push()`) and it doesn't free `p=info`.

I can't figure out why. Sorry for the long post. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**:
I changed `d` in the main function from `char d[]=""` to `char *d`, now the output is:

```
tops: helloooooooooo 
tops: helloworld 
tops: stringstring 
d = (null)
d = (null)
d = (null)
```

**EDIT2**:
Because I need to change `d` I need to send it's address, here is the correct code:

```
char d[]="";
while (pop(&s, &d))
{
    printf("d = %s ", d);
}
```

and the corresponding fix in `pop()`:

```
int pop(Stek *stek, void *element)
{
if (isEmptyStek(stek))
    return 0;

Cvor *p = stek->tos;

if (stek->copyFn)
{
    stek->copyFn(element, p->info); // <= !
}

...
```

**EDIT3**:
The variable `d` has to be freed separately to avoid leeks (thanks Valgrind):

```
char d[]="";
while (pop(&s, &d))
{
    printf("d = %s ", d);
    // do something else with it
    // ...
    free(d);
}
```

Comment: Your `pop` loop code produced the correct output. Why do you say that `pop` isn't working? Also, shouldn't `char d[]="";` be `char* d;`? You can't move or resize an array!

Comment: It's supposed to change the value of the variable `d`. That is, pop the top of stack to `d`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You are right. I changed it and updated my question. It set's `d` to null

Comment: `&element` is local variable address.

Comment: Why fragment your code into multiple blocks? It makes it hard/impossible for anyone to compile and run what you've got!

Comment: Careful with calling strlen on strings of a dubious source. It could cause undefined behavior if the string is not null termianted.

Comment: Unrelated, but `size_t` is unsigned, so it can't be `velInfo <= 0`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes! This led me to the fix. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Bob__ Nice catch, thanks.

Comment: @bodangly I will have to think about how to make it safer. Thanks for the heads up. Or I can just state that the argument must be a null terminated string...

Comment: @Flexo The whole code is in a couple of files. I thought it would be too much.

Comment: Can you confirm in a debugger or via printfs if your copy function is even called - perhaps `isEmptyStek()` is returning early?  Also `char d[]="";` in your main looks dubious, but is probably safe.   I'd just call it a pointer.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I checked, it's called. I already made the other change you are suggesting, see my edits.

Comment: If you have a debugger, can you confirm when you "lose" your data pointer?  That by itself should point out any error and is much easier than the internet debugging we are doing now.

Comment: `char d[]=""; ... free(d);` Nooooo! Do not `free` what is not allocated via `malloc` or its family! Also be careful not to cause out-of-range access!

Comment: @MikeCAT Don't worry I've changed it to `char *d`. See my edits.

Comment: No need to avoid tasty [leeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leek).  Good to avoid [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). ;-)

Comment: In the `pop` function, `stek->copyFn(&element, p->info);` is wrong because `element` is a local variable

Comment: You haven't posted enough code to answer your question. `push` in particular is important. Please post a MCVE.    It's unclear why you would use copyfunc in the pop function instead of just returning the popped item (it doesn't need to be copied since it is no longer in the stack)

Comment: You need to, by default, produce a minimal complete example for every question asked. It's not helpful or wise to rely on a "slow reveal" through a series of edits, that just wastes time for everyone.

Comment: @M.M It's supposed to be a generic function, and the copy function is just for `char*`.

Comment: we can't tell how to `pop` correctly since we do not know how the data is stored in your stack. that's why the `push` function is important

Comment: @M.M It's stored in a linked list.

Comment: sorry but you really have to post your code, nobody can guess what you did based on words.

Comment: @M.M I wrote what my problem was, fixed with the help of comments here, and wrote what I fixed and why it works now.

Answer (score 0):

The popping code should be:

```
char *d;

while (pop(&s, &d))
{
    printf("d = %s ", d);
    free(d);
}
```

The `pop` function writes the popped value to the memory pointed to by the argument. So you must supply a pointer to the area where you write the popped value. Passing `d` is no good, nor is passing pointer to a 1-byte char array.

**Note:** this may not be a complete answer. I think your `pop` function is also wrong but you have not posted enough code.